# Linear Programming: What exactly is the basis matrix B, and how do we find its inverse from a given simplex tableau?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

The explanation given in my textbook, where $A$ is the coefficient matrix of the linear program:

> Let $\mathbf{A}_j$ denote the $j^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$ and
> $\mathscr{B} = \{B_1,B_2,\dots,B_m\} ⊆ \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be such that
> the columns $\mathbf{A}_{B_1},
> \mathbf{A}_{B_2},\dots,\mathbf{A}_{B_m}$ are linearly independent.
> Then the $m×m$ matrix $B = [\mathbf{A}_{B_1}, \mathbf{A}_{B_2},\dots,
> \mathbf{A}_{B_m}]$ is invertible.
> Let $\mathscr{N} = \{1,2,\dots,n\} − \mathscr{B} = \{ℓ_1, ℓ_2,\dots, ℓ_{n−m}\}$ and $N = [\mathbf{A}_{ℓ_1}, \mathbf{A}_{ℓ_2} ,\dots, \mathbf{A}_{ℓ_{n−m}}]$.

I'm struggling to understand how $B$ isn't just always the identity matrix (if it's the linearly independent columns of the coefficient matrix), and I have so many questions. How *exactly* is $B$, or $B^{-1}$, obtained from a simplex tableau? I've had a ton of abstract stuff in this book so I'm looking for something at least mildly concrete and intuitive. I'm starting learning about the revised simplex method, so apparently this requires knowing exactly what $B^{-1}$ is on every iteration of the revised method.

Comment: What book? Can you provide the ISBN and page number?

Comment: @Gerald It's not so much a book as it is a pdf made by the professor specifically for his lectures at my university.

Comment: Can you clarify $B = \{B_1,B_2,...,B_m\} ⊆ \{1,2,...,n\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at an example: suppose that we have the system of equations
$$
   2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 + \phantom{1}x_4 + 0x_5 = 6 \\
   \phantom{1}x_1 + 2x_2 + 2x_3 + 0x_4 + \phantom{1}x_5 = 7
$$
which we can represent in matrix form as $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$:
$$
   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      1 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 
   \end{bmatrix}}_{A}
   \mathbf x = 
   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}6 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf b}.
$$
When we pick out the matrices $B$ and $N$, we just separate the columns of $A$ into two groups. For example, if $\mathscr B = \{1,2\}$ and $\mathscr N = \{3,4,5\}$, then we imagine rewriting the system of equations as
$$
   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      2 & 3 \\ 
      1 & 2  
   \end{bmatrix}}_{B}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}
+
   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      2 & 0 & 1 
   \end{bmatrix}}_{N}
\begin{bmatrix}x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}6 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Writing $\mathbf x_{\mathscr B}$ for $(x_1,x_2)$ and $\mathbf x_{\mathscr N}$ for $(x_3, x_4, x_5)$ (your course may use different notation), we have separated $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ into $B \mathbf x_{\mathscr B} + N \mathbf x_{\mathscr N} = \mathbf b$. If the matrix $B$ happens to be invertible, we can solve for $\mathbf x_{\mathscr B}$ in terms of $\mathbf x_{\mathscr N}$ as $\mathbf x_{\mathscr B} = B^{-1}(\mathbf b - N\mathbf x_{\mathscr N}).$

The restriction that the columns of $B$ must be independent is just there so that $B^{-1}$ exists. If we instead chose $\mathscr B = \{1,3\}$ and $\mathscr N = \{2,4,5\}$, we could still separate our system of equations into
$$
   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      2 & 4 \\ 
      1 & 2  
   \end{bmatrix}}_{B}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}
+
   \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
      2 & 0 & 1 
   \end{bmatrix}}_{N}
\begin{bmatrix}x_2 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}6 \\ 7\end{bmatrix},
$$
but now we cannot solve for $(x_1, x_3)$ in terms of $(x_2, x_4, x_5)$, because we cannot multiply by $B^{-1}$.

---

When it comes to finding $B^{-1}$ in the simplex tableau, the thing to remember is this. When the basic variables for a particular step of the simplex method are the variables indexed by $\mathscr B$, then (defining $B$ in terms of that $\mathscr B$ as in the question) the tableau should be a representation of the system of equations $$B^{-1}A \mathbf x = B^{-1}\mathbf b.$$
There are two cases you might be in:

1. If you're lucky, the system of equations $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ was obtained by adding slack variables to a system of inequalities. In that case, the last $n \times n$ square submatrix of $A$ is the identity matrix. (We see this in the numerical example above.) If so, then the last $n \times n$ square submatrix of $B^{-1}A$ is just $B^{-1}$, and so we see $B^{-1}$ in the tableau: it is the portion of the tableau corresponding to the slack variables.
2. If you're not that lucky, then there's no place in the tableau that directly represents $B^{-1}$, and we need to track it separately. We can still keep $B^{-1}$ updated between iterations by a simple rule: **whatever row operations you do to the tableau in the pivoting step, do them to $B^{-1}$ as well**. This is all you need to perform the revised simplex method.

Answer (score 1):

The Simplex Tableau can be generally represented as the following:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
BV & z & Variables                 & RHS             \\\hline
z    & 1                  & C_{BV}^TB^{-1}N-C_{NBV}^T & C_{BV}^TB^{-1}b \\\hline
     & 0                       &                           &    \\\
s_i  & 0                       & B^{-1}A                   &  B^{-1}b  \\
\text{or}   & 0                       & \text{or}                 &    \\
x_i   & 0                       & B^{-1}A_j                 &    \\       
\end{array}$$

from the following linear model:

$$\max z = c^Tx$$
$$\text{Subject to:}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$Ax\le b$$
$$x\ge 0$$

The $A$ matrix can be split into two components: the Non-Basic and Basic Variables coefficients (N and B respectively). The $B^{-1}$ matrix directly corresponds to the column values of the *slack* variables of that given iteration of the Simplex method. When you first start, it's going to be the identity matrix as the slack variables are all basic variables, for example from an abstracted starting tableau:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
BV  & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & RHS \\\hline 
z   & 1                  &     &     &     & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   \\\hline 
s_1 & 0                  &     &     &     & 1   & 0   & 0   &     \\
s_2                      & 0   &     &     &     & 0   & 1   & 0   &     \\
s_3                      & 0   &     &     &     & 0   & 0   & 1   &    
\end{array}

If I were to tell you that, $B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\  4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}$ for a given iteration of the simplex method, then you would know for that iteration:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
BV  & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & RHS \\\hline 
z   & 1   &     &     &     &    &    &    &    \\\hline 
    & 0   &     &     &     & 1   & 2   & 3   &     \\
    & 0   &     &     &     & 4   & 5   & 6   &     \\
    & 0   &     &     &     & 7   & 8   & 9   &    
\end{array}

Using the Revised Simplex Method, we'll take advantage of something called [ETA Matrices](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Eanstee/math340/340etamatrix.pdf#:%7E:text=Eta%20Matrices%20In%20computer%20implementations%20of%20the%20Revised,that%20updates%20B%3A%20%28new%20B%29%20%3D%20%28old%20B%29E) to update the old $B^{-1}$ into a new $B^{-1}$ per iteration, but the same idea still applies in that all we're doing in regards to $B^{-1}$ is denoting/updating the column values of the slack variables.